# how to control display output size in ipython

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sympy, mathjax

I have an ipython notebook and I want to write a function to display matrixes:

```
from IPython.display import display
import sympy
sympy.init_printing()
def print_matrix(a):
    display(sympy.Matrix(a))

import numpy as np
print_matrix(np.random.random((20, 20)))
```

This is producing a mathml output which is very large on my screen. How to control the size? I don't want to truncate numbers, I want to decrease the size of the fonts / size of the output image.

I have accomplished it with

```
sympy.init_printing(use_latex='png', fontsize='5pt')
```

but I don't like the png output, I would like the default mathjax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't save with the notebook (you'll probably need to execute some Javascript in a cell to do that), but if you right click on an equation there is an option to scale it up or down (this is a MathJax feature, which has nothing to do with the IPython notebook).

Comment: actually in my case the output are png images

Comment: I'm confused. You said in your question that you would prefer to use mathjax.

Comment: sorry, you are right. I have set it to png. Your solution works, but it would be better to specify it from python.